# No error/debugging info in Classic ASP app after SQL Server 2008 R2 install

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, sql-server-2008-r2

Yes, I have all the corresponding debugging options enabled in IIS, and error reporting was working fine just before installing SQL Server 2008 R2.

Now everytime I run a Classic ASP script, if there's an error, the page will just stop rendering at the error point, as usual, but will not display any error info.

I've googled this for hours to no avail so I will appreciate ANY ideas and solutions.

Comment: I don't know of any way that SQL Server could affect ASP's ability to render errors. Especially if the ASP script is not doing anything related to SQL Server.

Comment: I know, it doesn't make much sense to me either but that's the ONLY change I've made on my system (installing SQL Server) and now this is happening. ¿?

Comment: have you set the on error resume next statement on your asp code? Not sure if it will fix it but it's worth a try

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no, I haven't set `on error resume next`.

Comment: Probably would help to see what kind of code is causing it to do this.

Comment: Any code that will throw an ASP error will do it. And look at this, oddly enough, I have just disabled **server-side debugging** on IIS and now my pages are displaying the debug info again... ¿? This is not the normal behavior, is it?

Answer (score 2):

When server debugging is turned on the ASP script engine will pause when an error occurs and invoke the system debugging.  This usually results in the popup dialog on the console of the server (when a user is logged in) to ask the user (who is assumed to be a developer) what debugging tool he/she would like to use to start debugging the problem.

Unless you are actually in a position to be running a debugger (such as Visual Studio) on the server you should not have debugging enabled.

Comment: Thanks, that's clarifying, and I'll leave Server Debugging off from now on. Now just out of curiosity, what could SQL Server have done to cause IIS/.NET Framework to chage its behavior (or actually _activate_ its normal behavior)?

Comment: @Mark: Certainly this is not "its normal behavior" the server debugging setting has the default of false.  I have no idea how installing any update of anything would somehow manage to set it to true for your site.  Bizare.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this answer, I was troubleshooting for quite a while trying to figure out why a sql 2008 install would somehow mess up a classic asp environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same thing. The other change I had made to my server environment at the time was to upgrade to .Net4 framework on the site. So I'm not sure if it was the .Net framework causing my pages to stop rendering (rather than displaying an error), or if it truly is SQL Server 2008r2.

Comment: I'll also confirm that as Mark said, when I turn OFF Server Side Debugging, the error messages did return. Seems strange.